# SQL Code generated incorrectly using Entity Framework while using Left join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am using Entity Framework for executing code for left join and the SQL code that is being generated has mapping issue for one parameter

This mapping issue is when I am using `IQueryable` object on end of the join and the other end is context object.

If I use context object instead of `IQueryable`, then the SQL code generated is proper.

For example:

- DB entity name: `order`
- Property name: `OrderId`
- Mapped to table name : `Orders` & column `order_id`

If in my `IQueryable` object if I alias `OrderId` as `order_id` that resolves the issue as both my alias and my database column name is same so there is no mapping issue.

```
var query = (from o in context.Orders
             where o.BranchKey == branchKey
             select new 
                    {
                        o.OrderId, o.BranchKey
                    }); 

query = query.Skip(firstRecord).Take(count).AsQueryable();

var orderDetails = (from o in query
                    join od in context.OrderDetails
                         on new { o.orderId, o.BranchKey } equals new { od.OrderId, od.BranchKey } 
                    into ordergroup
                    from grp in ordergroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                           {
                               o.order_id, o.BranchKey
                           })
```

Expected result:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[OrderId], [t].[BranchKey]
    FROM (SELECT [o].[order_id] AS [OrderId], [o].[BranchKey]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [o]
    WHERE ((([o].[BranchKey] = @__branchKey_0) 
    OFFSET @__p_4 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_5 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS [t]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[order_details] AS [od] ON ([t].[orderId] = [od].[order_id]) AND ([t].[BranchKey] = [od].[BranchKey])
```

Actual result:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[OrderId], [t].[BranchKey]
    FROM (
    SELECT [o].[order_id] AS [OrderId], [o].[BranchKey]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [o]
    WHERE ((([o].[BranchKey] = @__branchKey_0) 
    OFFSET @__p_4 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_5 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS [t]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[order_details] AS [od] ON ([t].[order_id] = [od].[order_id]) AND ([t].[BranchKey] = [od].[BranchKey])
```

Comment: This is the most *minimal*, complete, and *verifyable* example of the problem that you are able to muster?

Comment: using indents can make a big difference.  On this website other people need to read your code -- be kind and indent in a way that make your code easier to read.  It will work for you too -- for example can you see above how the indenting made it clear there is an extra `}` in your code sample?  Where did that come from?

Comment: Please format the expected and output SQL as code too.

Comment: ok well you made change to the question and now my formatting does not work